# endpoint to output a autodesk checklist as a pdf file?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

Does anyone know if in Autodesk they have an exposed endpoint to produce a PDF in the same form that the one in their GUI produces?

I've looked at my web traffic and can see https://developer.api.autodesk.com/reports/v1/containers/id/reports is being called by their frontend, however, I can't find this as a documented exposed endpoint.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this endpoint is not exposed publicly, and it's for Autodesk internal use only as I know. Have you tried to make your report via calling either of them?

- https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/checklists-instances-GET/
- https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/checklists-instances-id-GET/

Comment: Hi Eason, Thank you for answering my question, I thought that was going to be the case I already am calling those endpoints was just trying to avoid duplication of work if you already had a Checklist report generation endpoint exposed.